# running multiple docker-compose file in isolation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to run multiple docker-compose files on the same machine, sometimes service names have conflicts if they are defined with the same name in both files?

I'm wondering if the solution is around creating separate networks for each so one is completely isolated from the other. The use case is development on the local machine.

*Both projects have a service name `product`.*

**Project A - docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:

  department:
    image: openjdk:jdk-alpine
    container_name: department
    ports:
      - 9081:8080
      - 65194:65193
    volumes:
      - ./Department.jar:/Department.jar
    command: java -jar Department.jar
```

**Project B - docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - 6603:3306

  department:
    image: node:10
    container_name: department
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    volumes:
      - "./department:/department"
```

**Error**

[image]

> Creating department          ...  Creating department          ...
>   error
>
> ERROR: for department  Cannot create container for service department:
>   Conflict. The container name "/department" is already in use by
>   container
>   "8174dc2133c6e3b8d55e533f692cbff25c26512a4a80591f46467c459bb0ae9a".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.

Comment: Doesn't matter. docker-compose create a network for each docker-compose file. The only way the network will be same in you configuration, and if my memory is not betraying me, is if those files live in a folder with the same name ( as it is used as a prefix in the name of the network by docker )

Comment: see my edits please for the error sceenshot and the description.

Comment: `container_name` must be different. you can just remove it

Comment: I see, so the container name is what's shared on my machine and is visible to localhost?

Comment: a random name will be generated for the container, right? Is there any use of container names when it comes to accessing it in context of intra-service communication, I've a situation when containers are acessing each other via and that's through their service `label:` name, just trying to understand the use of the `container_name` attribute here. Thanks

Comment: container_name won't be necessary for communication between containers in most cases. You can use the service name (which is a DNS name) and docker-compose will load balance via DNS. You'll likely only have one container of that service anyway. The name will be `{parent_folder}_{service}_1` by default if docker-compose starts it, so you can still do things like `docker attach myproj_department_1` if you need to.